# Unexpected Token '<' when trying to inject JQuery into JavaFx WebView

Tags: jquery, eclipse, javafx, javafx-2, eclipse-rcp

Basically I need to grab data in the form of a string (irrelevant to the question) and append it into a JavaFx WebView via Jquery. This link is where I found how to embedded Jquery and call jquery functions to a webview: https://community.oracle.com/message/10446280?tstart=1.'

To explain the code:
I am working in a eclipse rcp project where the main viewpart is a container for a javafx scene which houses a webview. The webengine loads a page. The code below, grabs the view, gets the scene, then gets the webview. The EditorPart grabs the contents of the currently active editor (which will eventually be injected into the webview). For now I just have some temp code for testing. ExecuteJquery can be explained better within the link.

The Code:

```
HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(event).getActivePage().showView("com.interpro.emmeclipse.views.PageBuilderPart");

                FXSceneProvider view = (FXSceneProvider) page.findView("com.interpro.emmeclipse.views.PageBuilderPart");
                Scene scene = (Scene) view.getScene();
                AnchorPane node = (AnchorPane)scene.getRoot();
                WebView webview = (WebView) node.getChildren().get(0);
                final WebEngine engine = webview.getEngine();



                final IEditorPart activeEditor = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().getActiveEditor();
                if (activeEditor != null) {
                    final IDocument doc = (IDocument) activeEditor.getAdapter(IDocument.class);
                    if(doc != null){
                        System.out.println(doc.get());
                        engine.documentProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Document>() {
                            @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Document> prop, Document oldDoc, Document newDoc) {
                              executejQuery(
                                engine, 
                                "$(\"#content\").append(<div class='ui-statusbar'><h5 class='ui-title'>Test</h5></div>);" 
                              );
                            }
                          });
                    }
                }

/**
   * Executes a script which may reference jQuery function on a document.
   * Checks if the document loaded in a webEngine has a version of jQuery corresponding to 
   * the minimum required version loaded, and, if not, then loads jQuery into the document 
   * from the default JQUERY_LOCATION.
   * @param engine the webView engine to be used.
   * @Param jQueryLocation the location of the jQuery script to be executed.
   * @param minVersion the minimum version of jQuery which needs to be included in the document.
   * @param script provided javascript script string (which may include use of jQuery functions on the document).
   * @return the result of the script execution.
   */ 
  private static Object executejQuery(final WebEngine engine, String minVersion, String jQueryLocation, String script) {
    return engine.executeScript(
      "(function(window, document, version, callback) { "
        + "var j, d;"
        + "var loaded = false;"
        + "if (!(j = window.jQuery) || version > j.fn.jquery || callback(j, loaded)) {"
        + "  var script = document.createElement(\"script\");"
        + "  script.type = \"text/javascript\";"
        + "  script.src = \"" + jQueryLocation + "\";"
        + "  script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {"
        + "    if (!loaded && (!(d = this.readyState) || d == \"loaded\" || d == \"complete\")) {"
        + "      callback((j = window.jQuery).noConflict(1), loaded = true);"
        + "      j(script).remove();"
        + "    }"
        + "  };"
        + "  document.documentElement.childNodes[0].appendChild(script) "
        + "} "
      + "})(window, document, \"" + minVersion + "\", function($, jquery_loaded) {" + script + "});"
    );
  }

  private static Object executejQuery(final WebEngine engine, String minVersion, String script) {
    return executejQuery(engine, DEFAULT_JQUERY_MIN_VERSION, JQUERY_LOCATION, script);
  }

  private Object executejQuery(final WebEngine engine, String script) {
    return executejQuery(engine, DEFAULT_JQUERY_MIN_VERSION, script);
  }
```

Stacktrace:

```
netscape.javascript.JSException: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
at com.sun.webpane.platform.WebPage.twkExecuteScript(Native Method)
at com.sun.webpane.platform.WebPage.executeScript(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.executeScript(Unknown Source)
at com.interpro.emmeclipse.commands.OpenPageBuilder.executejQuery(OpenPageBuilder.java:102)
at com.interpro.emmeclipse.commands.OpenPageBuilder.executejQuery(OpenPageBuilder.java:123)
at com.interpro.emmeclipse.commands.OpenPageBuilder.executejQuery(OpenPageBuilder.java:127)
at com.interpro.emmeclipse.commands.OpenPageBuilder.access$0(OpenPageBuilder.java:126)
at com.interpro.emmeclipse.commands.OpenPageBuilder$1.changed(OpenPageBuilder.java:69)
at com.interpro.emmeclipse.commands.OpenPageBuilder$1.changed(OpenPageBuilder.java:1)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$DocumentProperty.invalidate(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$DocumentProperty.access$300(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.dispatchLoadEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$LoadWorker.access$600(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine$PageLoadListener.dispatchLoadEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.webpane.platform.WebPage.fireLoadEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.webpane.platform.WebPage.fwkFireLoadEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.webpane.webkit.network.URLLoader.twkDidFinishLoading(Native Method)
at com.sun.webpane.webkit.network.URLLoader.access$1300(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.webpane.webkit.network.URLLoader$6.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2546)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3756)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the next line produces an error due to a lack of quotes:

```
"$(\"#content\").append(<div class='ui-statusbar'><h5 class='ui-title'>Test</h5></div>);"
```

try

```
"$(\"#content\").append(\"<div class='ui-statusbar'><h5 class='ui-title'>Test</h5></div>\");"
```